# how to know someone has a good connection via PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to know how much Internet connection speed someone has with PHP? I've seen a lot that a site says whether you have a good connection or not, like live.chess.com? (Actually its accurate)
How to know it with PHP?

Comment: are you wanting to embed this code in a php script that displays a user's connection speed when they browse to that page?

Comment: I would have thought the easiest way would be with AJAX. Send messages back and forth with javascript and php and time how long they take. Do it a bunch of times and take the average. Accuracy could vary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial task to do. You have to consider many other factors that may slow down the connection, such as work load on your server etc.

- If you just want to know whether the connection between your server and your user is good or not, you could use something like timing page load from a javascript, or so. You could use ping time, but that result wouldn't always represent the truth, since there might be a proxy / nat between you and the user. With the ajax request way, you still don't have the guarantee results are trustable.
- If you need that information for, example, decide which content to show the user (eg. switch between flash/html versions, ..), better way is always to *ask* the user which one wants to see.
- If you just want to show the user how good is his connection, or you need that information to be quite trustful, i'd recommend using an external service (for example, here in Italy I use test.ngi.it), that has everything needed to be (almost) sure measured values are realistic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wish to stick with PHP, put the following code at the very beginning of your PHP page:

```
<?
$load_time = microtime(); 
$load_time = explode(' ',$load_time); 
$load_time = $load_time[1] + $load_time[0]; 
$page_start = $load_time; 
?>
```

Put the following code at the end of your page right before the  tags:

```
<? 
$load_time = microtime(); 
$load_time = explode(' ',$load_time); 
$load_time = $load_time[1] + $load_time[0]; 
$page_end = $load_time; 
$final_time = ($page_end - $page_start); 
$page_load_time = number_format($final_time, 4, '.', ''); 
echo("Page generated in " . $page_load_time . " seconds"); 
?>
```

The load time will be displayed.

Comment: I think server workload will affect this script! It's not clients connection speed.

Comment: Yeah, that is measuring *page generation* time, not connection speed!

Comment: By the way, instead of doing all that split/sum/etc stuff, just use `microtime(TRUE);`. And read the functions documentation.